# Leading zeros in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have fields `hr` and `min`, both integers in my application. For `hr` field, if the user enters "1" I would like Rails to automatically pad it to "01" before saving it to the database. Also for the `min` field if the user enter "0" it should put in as "00".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 355, accepted):

It'd be better to store it as an integer and just display it as you described on runtime. Every language has its own way to pad zeros - for Ruby you can use [String#rjust](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-rjust). This method pads a string (right-justified) so that it becomes a given length, using a given padding character.

> **`str.rjust(integer, padstr=' ') → new_str`**
>
> If `integer` is greater than the length of `str`, returns a new `String` of length `integer` with `str` right justified and padded with `padstr`; otherwise, returns `str`.

```
some_int = 5
some_int.to_s.rjust(2, '0')  # => '05'
some_int.to_s.rjust(5, '0')  # => '00005'

another_int = 150
another_int.to_s.rjust(2, '0') # => '150'
another_int.to_s.rjust(3, '0') # => '150'
another_int.to_s.rjust(5, '0') # => '00150'
```

Answer (score 63):

You can transform the integer into a string of that kind with:

```
result_string = '%02i' % your_integer
```

This is independent from how it gets saved in the db.

- [RDoc Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf)
- [Explanation & Examples](http://idiosyncratic-ruby.com/49-what-the-format.html)

Answer (score 22):

This is also quite handy:

```
"%.2d" % integer
```

The resultant string will be of 2 characters and if the number is of less than 2 characters, then 0s will be present in the string

Answer (score 8):

You can't store `01` as integer. It will be converted to `1`

You can store it as a string, or you can show it as a string "01"

Comment: Store it as an integer and show it as a string (padded with 0's) would be my recommendation. Apache's Java StringUtils had a nice pad method like that. Found this thread on padding: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/82137

Answer (score 7):

I like the % operator, even though it seems to have gone out of favor...

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > '%02i' % 1
 => "01"
2.0.0-p247 :002 > '%2i' % 1
 => " 1"
2.0.0-p247 :003 > '%-2i' % 1
 => "1 "
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to achieve this is to pad your integer at display time, using sprintf:

```
f = sprintf '%04d', 49
# f = "0049"
```

Answer (score -5):

Try this and you can change them to match

```
def numeric92(num)
  if num.present?
    if num < 0 && num > -1
      ('-%05d' % num) + '.' + ('%.2f' % num).split('.').last
    else
      ('%06d' % num) + '.' + ('%.2f' % num).split('.').last
    end
  else
    '000000.00'
  end
end
```

Comment: What exactly `if num < 0 && num > -1` is?